# Drupal - Node Clone Alternatives

Tags: drupal-7

just want to ask if there are any other suggested alternatives for cloning a node for drupal 7. Now I know most of you will answer "Node Clone Module", but is there any other module out there that can do the same thing? Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your issue with using Node Clone?  An incompatibility?

Comment: For Drupal 8, I'd recommend [Entity Clone](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_clone).

Answer (score 6):

[Replicate](https://drupal.org/project/replicate) provides a main cloning function, along with several hooks to control exactly how a field is duplicated based on its type, add info after cloning, and supports custom fields and entities. It is intended to developers and does not contain any GUI (for the moment anyway).

The goal is to provide a way to easily clone any entity, and to allow developers to be able to control exactly how entities are replicated, based on their type or the fields they contain, and to be able to easily extend the replication control to custom fields or entities.

For UI: [Replicate UI](https://drupal.org/project/replicate_ui).

Answer (score 2):

[Node Export](https://drupal.org/project/node_export) allows you to export nodes and then import it into another Drupal installation, or on the same site.

It is quite more flexible and powerful than Node Clone module, it integrates with modules like Features, Feeds or View Bulk Operations, it has Drush interface (great!) and it supports several import/export formats, like json, csv or xml, so you can modify the data before import.

Its only dependency is [UUID module](https://drupal.org/project/uuid).

Answer (score 0):

There is also this module which seems to do pretty much the same thing in Drupal 8 - https://www.drupal.org/project/quick_node_clone